# Prove that $-\log{d} \leq H(A|B) \leq \log{d}$ for von Neumann entropy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, entropy

> I'm trying to prove that $-\log{d} \leq H(A|B) \leq \log{d}$ for [von Neumann entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy).

Now, for this to make sense I should give some definitions. System $A$ lives in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A$, system $B$ in $\mathcal{H}_B$, and these are finite dimensional systems. Moreover, system A has dimension $d$. $H(A|B)$ is the conditional entropy, which I here take to be $H(A|B) = H(AB) - H(B)$, where $H(A) = -Tr(\rho_A \log{\rho_A})$, $\rho_A$ being the density operator of system $A$, so that $H(AB)$ is the density operator of the joint system.

Now, I can prove the upperbound quite easily:

$H(A|B) = H(AB) - H(B) \leq H(A) + H(B) - H(B) \leq \log{d}$, where both inequalities follow from the positivity of the relative entropy $H(A||B) = Tr(\rho_A\log{\rho_A}-\rho_A\log{\rho_B})$ quite easily. If needed, I can write those two line proofs in an update.

However, for the lowerbound I'm quite lost. I'm pretty sure I need to make some clever choice of $A$ and $B$ for the relative entropy again and abuse its positivity, but I can't figure out what to do. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: What is $d$ here?

Comment: The dimension of Hilbert space $A$, so the number of elements in its basis.

Comment: Oh, don't know why I missed that initially. Thanks.

Comment: One can show this using strong subadditivity of the von Neumann entropy using a purification, but this seems like a bit of overkill.

Comment: As in, $H(AB|C) \leq H(A|C) + H(B|C)$, I suppose? I can look at that for a bit. What purification would you use?

Comment: Any purification is good. If you want I can write an answer.

Comment: That would be great, as I'm not seeing it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lower bound $-\log\,d\le H(A|B)$ follows from strong subadditivity,
$$
H(ABC)+H(B)\le H(AB)+H(BC)\ .
$$
To this end, choose a purification $\lvert\psi_{ABC}\rangle$ of $\rho_{AB}$.  Then, $H(ABC)=0$, and $H(BC)=H(A)$, and thus, we have
$H(B)\le H(AB) + H(A)$ (this is also known as the [Araki-Lieb inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy#Subadditivity)), which implies
$$
-\log\,d\le -H(A)\le H(AB)-H(B)=H(A|B)\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see indeed that it follows from strong subadditivity, however I don't see exactly how this is the Araki Lieb inequality. I tried doing it from that myself, and failed. I thought the Araki Lieb was the fact that $|H(A) - H(B)| \leq H(AB) \leq H(A) + H(B)$. How does one rewrite that to $H(B) \leq H(AB) + H(A)$? Maybe I'm just making a simple mistake, but the way I see it it states that $H(AB) - H(A) \leq H(B)$, which is not easily rewritten to the form you state as far as I can see. In fact, taking H(AB) to the other side and multiplying by -1 seems to give the opposite.

Comment: Disregard that last sentence starting with in fact, I was too late to edit that out. However, the rest is still a question!

Comment: $|H(A)-H(B)|\le H(AB)$ implies $H(B)-H(A)\le H(AB)$, which is equivalent to $H(B)\le H(AB)+H(A)$.

Comment: BTW, the Araki-Lieb inequality can be proven without using strong subadditivity (indeed, the Araki-Lieb paper predates the proof of strong subadditivity), so one indeed prove this without strong subadditivity.

Comment: Yes, one can prove the triangle inequality from the subadditivity and duality of the von Neumann entropy, which in essence is all we needed.

Comment: @user129412 What do you mean by "duality of the von Neumann entropy"?

Comment: I mean that $H(A) = H(B)$, for $\rho_{AB}$ pure.

Comment: I have to admit I do not see how this together with subadditivity allows to prove the triangle inequality (unless $\rho_{AB}$ is pure, of course).

Comment: The triangle equality follows from subadditivity by making use of duality as follows: Let R be a third
purifying reference system, so that $|\psi\rangle_{RAB}$ is a purification of $\rho_{AB}$. Then $H(B) = H(RA) \leq H(A) + H(R) = H(A) + H(AB)$. This implies $H(AB) \geq H(B) - H(A)$, and you get the absolute values by doing the proof with A and B reversed.